# add link back to item in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jquery and I'm having trouble with a simple task. I'd just like to create a list of links which point to all the h2s on the page. currently, my script does make the list, however it should be a link to the h2 on the page. I've simplified the page to make things a bit easier. Essentially when someone clicks on the list item, it should go to the item in the page. Thank you!

Rik

```
<body>
        <ul class="empty">
        </ul>
        <h2 class="hd0">content 1</h2>
        <h2 class="hd1">content 1</h2>
        <h2 class="hd1">content 1</h2>
    <script>
        $('h2').each(function () {
            $('.empty').append($('<li/>', {
                text: $(this).text()
            }))
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. It's built into browsers already via hash links. Just add some `a` tags with `href="#some-id"` and change your classes to ids:

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#hd-1">Link to heading 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hd-2">Link to heading 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hd-3">Link to heading 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h2 id="hd-1">Heading 1</h2>
  <h2 id="hd-2">Heading 2</h2>
  <h2 id="hd-3">Heading 3</h2>
</body>
```

That will do exactly what you want, no js required.

If you really want to dynamically build out the links, then you need to add `a` tags with hash links in the dynamically created `li`s. Something like this:

```html
<script>
  $('h2').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this)
    $('#jump-links').append('<li><a href="#' + $el.attr('id') + '">' + $el.text() + '</a></li>')
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by adding a data-id to act like a key for where you want to jump to. There are a lot of ways but This is how I would approach this. Good luck!

```js
var counter = 1;

$('h2').each(function() {

  // append the li with a data-id
  $('.empty').append("<li data-id=" + counter + ">" + $(this).text() + "</li>");

  // add a matching data-id to the h2 so we can link up
  $(this).attr('data-id', counter);

  // increment the counter for our ids
  counter++;
});

// when clicking on the list travel to the h2.
$("body").on("click", ".empty li", function() {

  // get the focus
  var focusOn = $("body").find("h2[data-id=" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "]");

  // scroll to the target
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: (focusOn.first().offset().top)
  }, 500);
  
  // some output text
  console.log(focusOn.html());
});
```

```css
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* ----------- */
/* for testing */
/* ----------- */
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="empty"></ul>
<h2 class="hd0">content 1</h2>
<h2 class="hd1">content 2</h2>
<h2 class="hd1">content 3</h2>
```